# "新しい参加者" 向けに要所要所でTipsを表示する仕組みが欲しい

Tags: 機能の要求

新しい参加者が質問を投稿した場合、しばらくの間は **その他のユーザー** 向けにユーザーカードでその旨と「行動規範に沿って暖かく迎えましょう」などのメッセージが表示されますが、スタック・オーバーフローにある程度慣れた利用者であれば信用度を見ればユーザーが新しい参加者なのは一目瞭然ですし、行動規範を守るのも当たり前(ですよね？)なので、これらのメッセージが有効なのかが少々疑問です。

慣れたユーザーに向けてよりも **新しい参加者** に対して、要所要所でTipsを表示する仕組みがあれば質問方法やサイトの使い方に迷わずに済みますし、コメントで都度フォローしてあげる周りのユーザーの負担も減るんじゃないかと思います。
(システムのルールで決まっているものを、人力に頼ってフォローして回るのはあまり効率的と言えない気がしています)

- 質問時に「よい質問をするには？」などのヘルプページ (現状でも表示されるが目立たない)
- 回答が付いた後に本人がページを開いたら「承認方法」を教えてあげる etc...

<sub>別アカウントを作ってしまうミスも、何か仕組みで防げないかなと思っています。</sub>

Comment: +1: 承認については、ポップアップで案内が出るなどしないかなと思っています。別アカウントを作ってしまうのはどのようなルートが典型的なのでしょうか（アカウントを作らずに質問　→　その後アカウントを作ると別になる？　会社でアカウントを作って質問　→　自宅で別アカウントを作ってしまう？）

Comment: モデレーター権限で接続元の情報を確認する限りは、前者の「未登録で質問 → 後からアカウント登録」という流れが大半だと思います。

Comment: 別アカウントを作ってしまうミスは、メールの確認を必須にすれば解決出来ると思うのですが、それは難しいのでしょうか？