# 承認ボタンを強調するデザイン変更はできないか

Tags: 討議, 機能の要求

先日に投票ボタンのデザイン変更がありました。
StackExchangeにて、この変更についてのアナウンス[We are graduating the updated button styling for vote arrows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389359/)が挙がっていて、リンク先の"What's next?"にて今回のデザイン変更は投票システムの包括的な探求活動の一環であると述べています。

この議論やデザインを眺めていて「投票ボタンの他に、承認ボタンも分かりやすいデザインに改善してほしい」と思い付きました。
なぜなら以前より、承認をせずに質問を繰り返す方や「解決しました。ありがとうございます」と回答欄にコメントするだけで済ませる方がいて、承認ボタンを認知していない人数が少なくないと感じていたためです。
承認をしない方にコメントで対応を促すことはできますが、コメントなしで気付く機会が増えるならばそれが最良だと思います。

本題です。
デザイン変更の機会に承認のアクションを促す動線や注意書きを追加することはできないでしょうか？

例えば下記のような実装方法が考えられます。

- 質問者に対しては、回答コメントのウォーターマークに`この回答で解決した場合は左側のチェックマークをクリックして承認してください。`の一文を追加する

  - 現在は`(前略)「+1」「ありがとうございます」などのコメントは避けてください。`と書かれているものの、解決時のアクションが書かれていない
- 質問者が未承認の回答欄を開いたとき、承認ボタンを点滅/バイブレーションさせたり、「解決したらここをクリック」バルーンを表示する
- 過去に一度も承認をしたことのない質問者のヘッダに「質問が解決したら[回答の承認](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1735/)をしましょう」注意書きを表示する

思い付きの提案ですし、重要性の高い課題ではありませんが、もし今回のような機会に今までより明瞭なデザインへと改善が進むと嬉しいです。

Comment: 過去の関連アイデア: ["新しい参加者" 向けに要所要所でTipsを表示する仕組みが欲しい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3232/3060), 承認に対する見解(承認よりプラス票が重要): [回答の承認をしない、または承認という機能を知らないユーザーが多い？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1784/3060)